# When uploading images in React I get internal server error

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I try to send post request with an Image but it throws error couldn't figure out why[image]

`const [image, setImage] = useState([]);`

```
    const handleImage = (event) => {
        setImage(...Array(event.target.files[0]))
    }
```

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {

        const fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('title', title);
        fd.append('prebuildImages', image);
  
        axios.post('/admin/prebuild', fd , {
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
        })
        .then(res => console.log(res))
    }
```

```
<input type="file" onChange={handleImage}/>
```

Comment: It's handled in server side. It returns status code 500. You should check api '/admin/prebuild'

Comment: yeah, it has to be sended in the form of array. but i dont know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

I used `import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';` package to choose or take camera pic,
it should be as FormData to send to server:

```
function selectPhotoTapped() {
const options = {
  quality: 1.0,
  maxWidth: 500,
  maxHeight: 500,
  storageOptions: {
    skipBackup: true,
  },
};

ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {
  if (response.didCancel) {
  } else if (response.error) {
  } else if (response.customButton) {
    // console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
  } else {
    const localTime = new Date().getTime();

    const data = new FormData();
    data.append('fileName', localTime + '.jpg');
    data.append('file', {
      name: localTime + '.jpg',
      uri: response.uri,
      type: response.type,
    });
    // call endpoint to send dataform
  }
});
```

}